# Apache Spark (2.0.2) Task is Out of Memory on repartition

Tags: apache-spark

I have a large spark job processing some 90 billion records. Everything runs fine until it gets to the re-partition part of the job for output to the final dataset. I currently re-partition down from 5600 tasks to 512. This stage OOM's on the last 2 tasks. The thing I don't understand is the output of one of the 512 files is only 256 MB uncompressed. Why is it going out of memory at 8G on this stage?

There are some 60 stages (all occur in the same job) prior to the final write. Would forcing an execution (via count) earlier upstream eliminate some overhead?

Running on 100 m4.xlarge, data is in parquet

Comment: please let me know the complete specs of your system.. there might be some coding or system issue while dealing with Spark. Please mention how you are accessing the records.. the question is unclear as there are nothing to understand what might have caused the situation.